# Would Legendre's Conjecture imply Riemann's Hypothesis?

Tags: prime-numbers, riemann-zeta

Riemann's hypothesis implies that the gap $g_n$ between primes is $$g_n=O(\sqrt{p_n}\log{p_n})$$
And Legendre's conjecture is equivalent to $$g_n=O(\sqrt{p_n})$$

Then, would proving the second conjecture imply the Riemann's Hypothesis to be true?

Comment: This question has [an answer there](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/482845/276986). The consequence of the RH on the prime gap [are not easy](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa41/aa4118.pdf).

Comment: That's right, I did not found that information. So sorry